# gEdit External Tools Output

Tags: gedit

I'm new to these forums, so I'm sorry if I've not put this in the correct place or followed forum rules.

I am writing a gEdit External Tools shell script.

In the 'Manage External Tools' dialogue box there is a drop down menu to choose the output.

These options are:

- Nothing
- Display in bottom pane
- Create new document
- Append to current document
- Replace current document
- Replace current selection
- Insert at cursor position

So the script can only use one of these.

I want to be able to choose the output from the script. Is there an output variable that can be set in the script? Is what I want even possible?

I've scoured the web for a solution, but to no avail, so I've come here for help.

Thank-you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on exactly *what* you want to do, but you definitely have some options:

Inside your script, you can use `> /dev/stderr` to redirect output to `stderr` -- that will make it appear in the "Shell Output" pane. In one script of mine that is set to "replace current document" I also write to the Shell Output pane with `echo "Something something" > /dev/stderr`

You can overwrite the current document the same way: `echo "Something something" > $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_NAME` will replace the current document with "Something something"

And you can append to current document with `>>` eg. `echo "Something something" >> $GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_NAME` will add "Something something" to the end of the current document.